# FullCalendar eventClick info.event.description

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

buenos dias quisiera encontrar la descripción de eventos en FullCalendar no me funciona

```
{
color: "#795548",
id: "16",
start: "2019-03-08 10:00:00",
end: "2019-03-08 12:35:00",
title: "nnnn",
description: "This is a cool event"
},
```

```
    eventClick: function(info) {
                console.log('Event: ' + info.event.description);
}
```

estoy con la version fullcalendar-4.0.1

Comment: No veo que el event tenga un campo description: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object. En cualquier caso te recomiendo completar el [tour], la pregunta tal cual está escrita no deja claro qué quieres obtener o qué problemas te has encontrado

Answer (score 1):

lo que deseaba es imprimir la descripcion que puse en el json atraves de eventClick

```
eventClick: function(info) {
        console.log(info.event._def.extendedProps.description);
}
```

esto me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes hacer algo así:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: source,
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next',
        right: ''
    },
    eventClick:  function(event, element) {
        //descripcion
        alert(event.description);
        //evento
        alert(event.title);
        //inicio evento
       alert(event.start);
       //fin evento
       alert(event.end);
    }
});
```

tambien puedes mirar el demo: [FullCalendar Description](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/fullcalendar-jquery-ui-modal/)